# Creating a legend with shapes using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, data-visualization

I have created the following code for a graph in which four fitted lines and corresponding points are plotted. I have problems with the legend. For some reason I cannot find a way to assign the different shapes of the points to a variable name. Also, the colours do not line up with the actual colours in the graph.

```
y1 <- c(1400,1200,1100,1000,900,800)
y2 <- c(1300,1130,1020,970,830,820)
y3 <- c(1340,1230,1120,1070,940,850)
y4 <- c(1290,1150,1040,920,810,800)

df <- data.frame(x,y1,y2,y3,y4)


g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x), shape="shape") +
  geom_smooth(aes(y=y1), colour="red", method="auto", se=FALSE) + geom_point(aes(y=y1),shape=14) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y=y2), colour="blue", method="auto", se=FALSE) + geom_point(aes(y=y2),shape=8) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y=y3), colour="green", method="auto", se=FALSE) + geom_point(aes(y=y3),shape=6) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y=y4), colour="yellow", method="auto", se=FALSE) + geom_point(aes(y=y4),shape=2) +
  ylab("x") + xlab("y") + labs(title="overview")
  geom_line(aes(y=1000), linetype = "dashed")
  theme_light() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=12, face="italic", hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_shape_binned(name="Value g", values=c(y1="14",y2="8",y3="6",y4="2"))

print(g)
```

I am wondering why the colours don't match up and how I can construct such a legend that it is clear which shape corresponds to which variable name.

Answer (score 1):

While you can add the legend manually via `scale_shape_manual`, perhaps the adequate solution would be to reshape your data (try using `tidyr::pivot_longer()` on `y1:y4` variables), and then assigning the resulting variable to the shape aesthetic (you can then manually set the colors to your liking). You would then need to use a single `geom_point()` and `geom_smooth()` instead of four of each.

Also, you're missing a reproducible example (what are the values of `x`?) and your code emits some warnings while trying to perform loess smoothing (because there's fewer data points than need to perform it).

**Update** (2021-12-12)
Here's a reproducible example in which we reshape the original data and feed it to ggplot using its `aes()` function to automatically plot different `geom_point` and `geom_smooth` for each "y group". I made up the values for the `x` variable.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

x <- 1:6
y1 <- c(1400,1200,1100,1000,900,800)
y2 <- c(1300,1130,1020,970,830,820)
y3 <- c(1340,1230,1120,1070,940,850)
y4 <- c(1290,1150,1040,920,810,800)

df <- data.frame(x,y1,y2,y3,y4)

data2 <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(y1:y4, names_to = "group", values_to = "y")

ggplot(data2, aes(x, y, color = group, shape = group)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +    # increased size for increased visibility
  geom_smooth(method = "auto", se = FALSE)
```

Run the code line by line in RStudio and use it to inspect `data2`. I think it'll make more sense here's the resulting output:

[image]

**Another update**

Freek19, in your second example you'll need to specify both the shape and color scales manually, so that ggplot2 considers them to be the same, like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

data <- ... # from your previous example

ggplot(data, aes(x, y, shape = group, color = group)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_shape_manual("Program type", values=c(1, 2, 3,4,5)) +
  scale_color_manual("Program type", values=c(1, 2, 3,4,5))
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you elaborate a little bit more? Why would reshaping the data help and why would I only need a single geom_point and geom_smooth? The values of x are just the input values of a certain function. I have four different vectors with outputs, each of them corresponding to a specific value for a certain parameter in my function. I tried to use pivot_longer, but I don't really understand how it would help

Comment: I updated the post with an example you can run in R.

Comment: I updated the post again with a solution for the duplicate legends. In short, once you specify the title for the shape scale, ggplot considers it different from the color scale, and draws both.
The solution is to manually specify both scales, exactly the same (then ggplot will render only one, because it will correctly assume they're the same scale).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get close to what I want, using:

```
library(ggplot2)


data <- data.frame(x = c(0,0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.1),
                   y = c(1400,1200,1100,1000,910,850, #y1
                         1300,1130,1010,970,890,840,  #y2
                         1200,1080,980,950,880,820, #y3
                         1100,1050,960,930,830,810, #y4
                         1050,1000,950,920,810,800), #y5
                   
                   group = rep(c("5%","6%","7%","8%","9%"), each = 6))
data

Values <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y, shape = group, color = group)) +    # Create line plot with default colors
  geom_smooth(aes(color=group)) + geom_point(aes(shape=group),size=3) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1, 2, 3,4,5))+
  geom_line(aes(y=1000), linetype = "dashed") +
  ylab("V(c)") + xlab("c") + labs(title="Valuation")+
  theme_light() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=12, face="italic", hjust = 0.5))+
  labs(group="Program Type")

Values
```

I am only stuck with 2 legends. I want to change both name, because otherwise they overlap. However I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Please see the updated answer, I think it can help you.